# LINQ return Mixed Date Between Two Tables With Many-To-One Relation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to return to the view a mixed result between 2 tables there is a many to one relation between them. I know this is possible but I'm still in the beginning stage in programming world so i need a little help to do that!

**Note**: If the query in LINQ will be better.

so here is my view model:

```
 public class HomeVM
    {

        public List<Post> Comics { set; get; }
        public List<Post> UpdatedComics { set; get; }
        public List<Post> Manga { set; get; }
        public List<Post> UpdatedManga { set; get; }
        public List<Post> Trending { set; get; }
        public IList<Chapter> Chapter{ set; get; }
}
```

Here is the Post Table:

```
public Post()
    {
        Chapter = new HashSet<Chapter>();
    }

    public int PostID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Chapter> Chapter { get; set; }
```

Here is the Chapter Table:

```
[Table("Chapter")]
public partial class Chapter
{
    public int ChapterID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Chapter Name")]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string ChapterName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Chapter Slug")]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string ChapterSlug { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Chapter Number")]
    public double ChapterNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Post Id")]
    public int PostID { get; set; }

    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
  }
```

As you see that was my View Model and simply there is a relation between Post Table and Chapter table where it's many from Chapter side to one. Also the Forging key between them is called **PostID**.

Now i want to return from my controller to my view a mixed date from both table but i don't know how to write the LINQ query to do that since the data mixed and i can't return mixed data in my view model .. So how i can solve this .

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  You need to at least post the structure of Post and Chapter, and you need to explain what you mean by "mixed date", maybe even give some sample data for both tables and the resulting output you want.

Comment: Hello ... I updated it ... about mixed content i mean that i want to return data from both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all your objects from table Post:
_repository() is IRepository

```
using( var repository = _repository() )
{
   var postObjectList = await repository().Get<Post>.Where(_if you need 
   conditions_).Include( a => 
   a.Chapter).ToListAsync();
}
```

This will get you all Post objects that have the condition from Where clause, with Chapters included. Same structure for the other table.

See IRepository, async methods, await/task.result first of all if you are new to this.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks . But To return them to view and fetch them there what i need ? i mean since i'm using VM What i should define there ? List ?

Comment: Are you using MVC or WebApi?